# Find and replace a list of words in PowerPoint presentation, including tables, with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, replace, powerpoint

I have been trying to solve this issue for a couple of days and am very stuck despite googling around a lot, so would really appreciate any pointers :)

So I am trying to replace a list of words by another (my file is a template used for several projects). It worked all right in textboxes, but did not work for tables so I have tried to adjust the textboxes code to tables. The below code runs without giving me an error message, but still does not edit my tables...

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire PowerPoint presentation

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
Dim FindList As Variant
Dim ReplaceList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tbl As Table


' INSERT THE LIST OF MERGE FIELDS HERE
FindList = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")

' INSERT THE LIST OF VARIABLES TO BE INSERTED BY HERE  
ReplaceList = Array("word1.1", "word2.1", "word3.1")


'Loop through each slide in Presentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes

        '''''for tables
        If shp.HasTable Then

                'give name to table
                Set tbl = shp.Table

                'loops on table rows and columns
                For i = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count

                        'Store cell text into a variable
                        ShpTxt = tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange


                          'Ensure There is Text To Search Through
                          If ShpTxt <> "" Then
                             For x = LBound(FindList) To UBound(FindList)

                             'Store text into a variable
                            'Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

                             'Find First Instance of "Find" word (if exists)
                             Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
                              FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                              Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                              WholeWords:=False)

                             'Find Any Additional instances of "Find" word (if exists)
                              Do While Not TmpTxt Is Nothing
                                Set ShpTxt = ShpTxt.Characters(TmpTxt.Start + TmpTxt.Length, ShpTxt.Length)
                                Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
                                  FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                                  Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                                  WholeWords:=False)
                              Loop
                             Next x
                          End If


                     Next j
                Next i
        Else


        ''''for all shapes excluding tables
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then

           'Store shape text into a variable
           Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

            'Ensure There is Text To Search Through
             If ShpTxt <> "" Then
                For x = LBound(FindList) To UBound(FindList)

                'Store text into a variable
                'Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

                'Find First Instance of "Find" word (if exists)
                Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
                  FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                  Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                  WholeWords:=False)

                'Find Any Additional instances of "Find" word (if exists)
                Do While Not TmpTxt Is Nothing
                  Set ShpTxt = ShpTxt.Characters(TmpTxt.Start + TmpTxt.Length, ShpTxt.Length)
                  Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
                    FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                    Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                    WholeWords:=False)
                Loop
               Next x
            End If

        End If

        End If

    Next shp

Next sld


End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken your code and refactored it a bit, in order to improve it's readability and maintainability.

Since you had everything in a single `Sub`, it can be harder to comprehend everything that's there, especially when there are big sections of code in different parts of an `If` statement. So your main routine ends up looking like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Multi_FindReplace()
    'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire PowerPoint presentation

    ' INSERT THE LIST OF MERGE FIELDS HERE
    Dim FindList As Variant
    FindList = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")

    ' INSERT THE LIST OF VARIABLES TO BE INSERTED BY HERE
    Dim ReplaceList As Variant
    ReplaceList = Array("word1.1", "word2.1", "word3.1")

    'Loop through each slide in Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            '''''for tables
            If shp.HasTable Then
                ReplaceWordsInTable shp, FindList, ReplaceList

            ElseIf shp.HasTextFrame Then
                ReplaceWordsInTextFrame shp, FindList, ReplaceList
            Else
                '--- doing nothing for all other shapes (at this time)
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```

It's easier to understand now, and very clear that you're handling `TextFrames` differently than handling `Tables`. Plus, this organization reduces your top-level routine to basic setup and initialization, then high-level logic flow.

Next, look at the two "ReplaceWords" subroutines:

```
Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTable(ByRef shp As Shape, _
                                ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    'give name to table
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = shp.Table

    'loops on table rows and columns
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
    Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
    For i = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count
            'Store cell text into a variable
            Set ShpTxt = tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
            If ShpTxt <> "" Then
                ReplaceWordsInTextRange ShpTxt, FindList, ReplaceList
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTextFrame(ByRef shp As Shape, _
                                    ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                    ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    'Store shape text into a variable
    Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
    Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
    If ShpTxt <> "" Then
        ReplaceWordsInTextRange ShpTxt, FindList, ReplaceList
    End If
End Sub
```

Each of these subs has logic that is specific to pulling apart a text frame or a table. But notice in your original code that the replacement code is really identical. So that is a separate routine now.

By separating the actual replacement action, it's "functionally isolated" and now makes your code consistent and easier to maintain. You're doing one thing in one place. If there's a problem, just fix it there.

```
Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTextRange(ByRef thisRange As TextRange, _
                                    ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                    ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
    Dim foundWord As TextRange
    Dim x As Long
    Dim nextCharPosition As Long
    Dim finished As Boolean
    nextCharPosition = 0
    For x = LBound(FindList) To UBound(FindList)
        finished = False
        Do While Not finished
            '--- find the word first, and capture the case of the starting character
            Set foundWord = thisRange.Find(FindWhat:=FindList(x), After:=nextCharPosition, _
                                           MatchCase:=msoFalse, _
                                           WholeWords:=msoFalse)
            If Not foundWord Is Nothing Then
                Dim firstCharUpper As Boolean
                firstCharUpper = (foundWord.Characters(0, 1) = UCase(foundWord.Characters(0, 1)))
                Set TmpTxt = thisRange.Replace(FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                                               Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                                               MatchCase:=msoFalse, _
                                               WholeWords:=msoFalse)
                nextCharPosition = TmpTxt.Start + Len(ReplaceList(x))
                If firstCharUpper Then
                    thisRange.Characters(TmpTxt.Start, 1) = UCase(thisRange.Characters(TmpTxt.Start, 1))
                End If
            Else
                finished = True
            End If
        Loop
    Next x
End Sub
```

You'll notice the loop is simplified to a single `Replace` statement (so you don't have to perform *find-the-first-word-then-try-again* logic). Also, I found in my testing that if a word on the `FindList` was located and started with an uppercase letter, the replacement action would leave it as a lowercase word. So I implemented a `Find` statement so that we can capture the case of the first letter and re-set that first letter after the replacement.

Here's the whole module is a single block:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Multi_FindReplace()
    'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire PowerPoint presentation

    ' INSERT THE LIST OF MERGE FIELDS HERE
    Dim FindList As Variant
    FindList = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")

    ' INSERT THE LIST OF VARIABLES TO BE INSERTED BY HERE
    Dim ReplaceList As Variant
    ReplaceList = Array("word1.1", "word2.1", "word3.1")

    'Loop through each slide in Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            '''''for tables
            If shp.HasTable Then
                ReplaceWordsInTable shp, FindList, ReplaceList

            ElseIf shp.HasTextFrame Then
                ReplaceWordsInTextFrame shp, FindList, ReplaceList
            Else
                '--- doing nothing for all other shapes (at this time)
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTable(ByRef shp As Shape, _
                                ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    'give name to table
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = shp.Table

    'loops on table rows and columns
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
    Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
    For i = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count
            'Store cell text into a variable
            Set ShpTxt = tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
            If ShpTxt <> "" Then
                ReplaceWordsInTextRange ShpTxt, FindList, ReplaceList
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTextFrame(ByRef shp As Shape, _
                                    ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                    ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    'Store shape text into a variable
    Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
    Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
    If ShpTxt <> "" Then
        ReplaceWordsInTextRange ShpTxt, FindList, ReplaceList
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceWordsInTextRange(ByRef thisRange As TextRange, _
                                    ByRef FindList As Variant, _
                                    ByRef ReplaceList As Variant)
    Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
    Dim foundWord As TextRange
    Dim x As Long
    Dim nextCharPosition As Long
    Dim finished As Boolean
    nextCharPosition = 0
    For x = LBound(FindList) To UBound(FindList)
        finished = False
        Do While Not finished
            '--- find the word first, and capture the case of the starting character
            Set foundWord = thisRange.Find(FindWhat:=FindList(x), After:=nextCharPosition, _
                                           MatchCase:=msoFalse, _
                                           WholeWords:=msoFalse)
            If Not foundWord Is Nothing Then
                Dim firstCharUpper As Boolean
                firstCharUpper = (foundWord.Characters(0, 1) = UCase(foundWord.Characters(0, 1)))
                Set TmpTxt = thisRange.Replace(FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
                                               Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
                                               MatchCase:=msoFalse, _
                                               WholeWords:=msoFalse)
                nextCharPosition = TmpTxt.Start + Len(ReplaceList(x))
                If firstCharUpper Then
                    thisRange.Characters(TmpTxt.Start, 1) = UCase(thisRange.Characters(TmpTxt.Start, 1))
                End If
            Else
                finished = True
            End If
        Loop
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply PeterT it is amazing!
Sorry I took a while to reply myself - I was not able to test thoroughly until just now.

The code is working well. I have noticed that in my bigger file with more occurrences (I have not reproduced that on a test file), sometimes an element of the list gets "forgotten" by the macro, but if I run it again straight away it gets replaced, so I am unsure what the issue is - although running the macro twice may be the easiest workaround!
I will add another comment if I understand the issue better
Anyway many many thanks for your help!!!